# How to get SVMs to play nicely with missing data in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn for some data analysis, and my dataset has some missing values (represented by `NA`).  I load the data in with `genfromtxt` with `dtype='f8'` and go about training my classifier.

The classification is fine on `RandomForestClassifier` and `GradientBoostingClassifier` objects, but using `SVC` from `sklearn.svm` causes the following error:

```
    probas = classifiers[i].fit(train[traincv], target[traincv]).predict_proba(train[testcv])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 409, in predict_proba
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 534, in _validate_for_predict
    X = atleast2d_or_csr(X, dtype=np.float64, order="C")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 84, in atleast2d_or_csr
    assert_all_finite(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 20, in assert_all_finite
    raise ValueError("array contains NaN or infinity")
ValueError: array contains NaN or infinity
```

What gives?  How can I make the SVM play nicely with the missing data?  Keeping in mind that the missing data works fine for random forests and other classifiers..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do data imputation to handle missing values before using SVM.

EDIT: In scikit-learn, there's a really easy way to do this, illustrated on [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values).

(copied from page and modified)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
>>> # missing_values is the value of your placeholder, strategy is if you'd like mean, median or mode, and axis=0 means it calculates the imputation based on the other feature values for that sample
>>> imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
>>> imp.fit(train)
Imputer(axis=0, copy=True, missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', verbose=0)
>>> train_imp = imp.transform(train)
```

Comment: What about Infinite values? This indicates a strategy only with NaN (i.e. division by zero)

Comment: I did this but the transformation changed the data to a non integer array. If I don't impute the svm classification works fine, but when I impute the data I get the error `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`. Any tips ?

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated. I always end up with: "ImportError: cannot import name 'Imputer' from 'sklearn.preprocessing'".

Answer (score 6):

You can either remove the samples with missing features or replace the missing features with their column-wise medians or means.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular answer here is outdated. "Imputer" is now "SimpleImputer". The current way to solve this issue is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317119/classifiers-in-scikit-learn-that-handle-nan-null). Imputing the training and testing data worked for me as follows:

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp = imp.fit(x_train)

X_train_imp = imp.transform(x_train)
X_test_imp = imp.transform(x_test)
    
clf = svm.SVC()
clf = clf.fit(X_train_imp, y_train)
predictions = clf.predict(X_test_imp)
```