# sklearn Imputer() returned features does not fit in fit function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a feature matrix with missing values NaNs, so I need to initialize those missing values first.  However, the last line complains and throws out the following line of error: 
**`Expected sequence or array-like, got Imputer(axis=0, copy=True, missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', verbose=0)`**.
I checked, it seems the reason is that train_fea_imputed is not in np.array format, but sklearn.preprocessing.imputation.Imputer form. How should I fix this?
BTW, if I use **train_fea_imputed = imp.fit_transform(train_fea)**, the code works fine, but train_fea_imputed return an array with 1 dimension less than train_fea

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

    imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
    train_fea_imputed = imp.fit(train_fea)

    # train_fea_imputed = imp.fit_transform(train_fea)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5000,n_jobs=1, min_samples_leaf = 3)
    rf.fit(train_fea_imputed, train_label)
```

update: I changed to

```
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=1)
```

and now the dimension problem did not occur. I think there is some inherent issues in the imputing function. I will come back when I finish the project.

Comment: Can you make a sample `train_fea` and `train_label` with dummy values so I can run this on my computer? e.g. like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30319249/238639

Comment: @bakkal    I think you can use numpy to generate random matrix and mask them with NaN to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `scikit-learn`, initialising the model, training the model and getting the predictions are  seperate steps. In your case you have:

```
train_fea = np.array([[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,np.nan,0]])
train_fea
array([[  1.,   1.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.],
       [  1.,  nan,   0.]])

#initialise the model
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)

#train the model
imp.fit(train_fea)

#get the predictions
train_fea_imputed = imp.transform(train_fea)
train_fea_imputed
array([[ 1. ,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 1. ,  0.5,  0. ]])
```

Comment: your solution indeed returns the train_fea_imputed with a dimension lower than my original train_fea. I think it is equivalent to apply fit_transform directly. My problem is that I need to have apply feature_score later in random forest. If I have fewer dimension, I have no way to associate the score with feature name.

Comment: I've added an example matrix to my answer, I don't seem to be having problems with dimensionality?

Comment: I changed the Imputer parameter axis = 1 and now the problem is fixed. I think my train_fea has some wield columns

Answer (score 1):

I think that axis = 1 is not correct in this case since you want to take mean across the values of feature vector/column (axis = 0) and not row (axis = 1).