# Imputer mean strategy removes NaN instead of replacing

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to replace NaN values in a given dataset by the column mean using `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer`. Instead of having `NaN` replaced I instead find that they are being removed by my code. Here is a short example demonstrating this issue I am facing:

```
>>> test_data = np.array([float("NaN"), 1, 2, 3])
>>> imp = Imputer(missing_values=float("NaN"), strategy="mean")
>>> imp.fit_transform(test_data)
** Deprecation warning truncated **
array([[1., 2., 3.]])
```

What should I change so that instead of removing the `NaN` it gets replaced by `2.` ?

I tried to adapt from the `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer` [user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation) and was originally following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317119/classifiers-in-scikit-learn-that-handle-nan-null) but I must have misunderstood them.

Edit:

I have also tried the following, which gets rid of the deprecation warning but does not change the end result:

```
>>> test_data = np.array([[float("NaN"), 1, 2, 3]])
>>> imp = Imputer(missing_values=float("NaN"), strategy="mean")
>>> imp.fit_transform(test_data)
array([[1., 2., 3.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The Imputer expects a data frame. This works as expected -

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

test_series = pd.Series([float("NaN"), 1, 2, 3])
test_data_frame = pd.DataFrame({"test_series": test_series})
imp = Imputer(missing_values=float("NaN"), strategy="mean")
test_data_frame = imp.fit_transform(test_data_frame)
print(test_data_frame)
```

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to work whether axis is set to 0 or 1 whereas my solution using a numpy array works exclusively by using either columns or rows, depending how the data was arranged.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to my question by re-reading the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) for `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer`. It turns out that I was leaving out the `axis` parameter of the `Imputer()` 'constructor'. By default, it is set to 0 (apply strategy on columns) but I was passing a row of data so I should have used axis = 1.

This is the end result, as expected initially.

```
>>> test_data = np.array([float("NaN"), 1, 2, 3])
>>> imp = Imputer(missing_values=float("NaN"), strategy="mean", axis=1)
>>> imp.fit_transform(test_data)
array([[2., 1., 2., 3.]])
```